# Why is my "if b4price is not None" not working - I am always getting an AttributeError: Nonetype. Works until it hits an empty variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code I have is pretty long so I only copied the part that I am having trouble with.

My problem seems to by hitting a `None` variable. From the webpage I am scraping I can see that at a certain point in each item there is no `<div class="old-price">` just a `<div class="price">` since it has not been reduced on that specific item.

I am trying to either have the code skip the `None` variables and just go to the next item to see if it has `<div class="old-price">` and keep on scraping, but I allways fail. I have also tried to have it just grab the `<div class="price"`> when the old does not exist but without success.

The Error I get I have attached to this question
Hope someone here can help me.

```
for item in items:
    a = item.find(attrs={'class':'offer-list-img'}).find(name='a')
    item_href = a.attrs['href']
    item_title = a.attrs['title'].split('(')[0].strip()
    b4price = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'}) == None
    pass

    if b4price is not None:
        b4price = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'}).get_text().strip()
    print b4price
```

[This is the Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IquFt.png)

Comment: What this tells you is that `item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'})` returns `None`. Thus, you cannot call a method (like `get_text`) on it. Also, you assign `b4price` to `True` or `False` in the line before, so it will never be `None`...

Comment: `b4price` will be either `True` or `False` because `==` operator returns one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the variable `b4price` is a boolean value:

```
b4price = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'}) == None
```

If `item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'})` is `None`, `b4price` will be `True`, otherwise `False`. Then, in the next line you check for `b4price` not being `None`, which is always the case.

And finally, you make another mistake, the function `item.find` seems to return `None` when nothing is found. Therefore, the method `get_text` is called on `None` and you get your `AttributeError`.

In order to fix the error, you need to check that the result of `item.find` is not `None`. Something like this:

```
res = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'})
if res is not None:
  res.get_text()  # etc, etc
```

Answer (score -1):

Change line with `b4price` assignment from

```
b4price = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'}) == None
```

to next one:

```
b4price = item.find(attrs={'class':'old-price'}) or None
```

Comment: @bgusach It would assign result of item.find or None, not None or None

Comment: If the result of find is None, you are storing None anyway. The error is by no means there.

Comment: @bgusach what if item.find returns empty list [] ?

Comment: I got no idea how the API looks like, but it would be pretty broken if it can return `None` and `[]`. Either you return a single element, with `None` signalizing failure, or you return a list with all the matches, eventually empty.

Comment: @bgusach It would return None or list with items, if it's none after `if b4price is not None` checking value of b4price would be reassigned...

Comment: I find hard to believe that the `find` method can return `None` or `[]`. First, because it makes no sense, and last but most important, because the OP did not provide too much information as to what framework/library he is using, so I doubt that you could check the documentation.

Comment: @bgusach it doesn't matter what is API of find as long as it return falsy value, because each time when result of items.find would be falsy b4price would be equal to None, that's what needed for further checking ... that's why i've proposed to use `or` operator ...

Comment: Lol, sure my friend. Have a nice day ;)